# Which to use Timer or ThreadPool in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have an application in java in which I need to schedule commands to run after a given delay, what should I use Timer or ThreadPool and Why?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Rationale: it is *much* easier to use than `Timer` or `TimerTask`.

You can obtain one using, for instance, [`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the suggession, but I am not bothered with implementation, Is there any other rationale in using it.

Comment: @AnkitZalani Well yes, it Just Works(tm), it has been written by people who really know their stuff, as such it is essentially bug-free ;) Plus, you have all of `ExecutorService` at your disposal too

Comment: I couldn't recollect exact scenario, but I think if you have moving "interval", then TimerTask implementation will be easy because you don't need to create entire ThreadPool with new interval everytime.

Comment: @Nambari you can schedule any task at any interval you wish; when you initiate a `ScheduledExecutorService`, you do not specify a defined interval, it is at your leisure. Note that it can do one shots as well as periodics -- or immediates if you use, say, `.execute()` (which is has since it inherits `ExecutorService`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring, another solution is [`@Scheduled`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html). Simply annotate a desired method with that annotation and specify the delay or a certain time at which you want to be called. The advantage is that you do not need a new class implementing Runnable and concern yourself with multiple thread (although Executors frameworks is easy to use). But you need the class having the method with the annotation to be a Spring Bean; also the method needs to return void and have no arguments.

It's actually this simple:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)//the method is called once every 5 seconds
public void myScheduledMethod() {
    //do you stuff
}
```